# NGINX: Rewrite image location

Tags: image, nginx, location, url-rewriting

I am using NGINX for a project, and I have WordPress installed.
I would like to hide the wp-content directory and want to rewrite the image URLs for images.

I want to support multiple extensions (jpg,jpeg,gif,png).

Another thing that I needed is a dynamic folder, it contains the ID of a user.

I used the following code but without luck, The number `1` should also become dynamic but for now I want to start with a simply rewrite, to keep things simple.

```
location /images/auctions/1/(.*).(png|jpg|gif) {
        rewrite /wp-content/plugins/myplugin/uploads/auctions/1/(.*).(png|jpg|gif) /images/auctions/1/$1.$2;          
}
```

I searched for NGINX rewrite and some other search queries but nothing that really answers my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I think I got some kind of way that works for me (only not yet with the dynamic folder `/1/` but I probably will fix that later).

Here is the code for the nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/images/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-content/plugins/myplugin/uploads/$1;
}
```

**Edit:**

Below the code that also handles the dynamic ID folder of the user:

```
location ~ ^/images/(.*)/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-content/plugins/veilgarant/uploads/$1/$2;
}
```